# How to start activity only once on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start activity only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351045/start-activity-only-once)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), deneme.class);


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      if(!settings.getString(Constants.NAME, "").equals("") && !settings.getString(Constants.SURNAME,  "").equals("")  
            && !settings.getString(Constants.NUMBER, "").equals("")) {

        startActivity(intent);

    }
      //settings is my shared preferences object 

    else{   
     setContentView(R.layout.information_form_layout);

    // this part creates a shared preferences and save the values for the first time
```

I want to start other activity if the values saved with shared preferences are not empty. If the person starts the activity first time then the else part should work and the values should be filled fully.

Where i got it wrong? Thanks for help.

I just did as Henspeide said but it still forces to close.

settings is shared preferences object.

settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 1):

Call setContentView(..) immediately after super.onCreate(..):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_time_startup_activity);

    if (..do settings checks here...){
        startActivity(..)
    }    
}
```